# Window's Background Colour Different than ViewController's Background Colour

Tags: ios, swift

I have used `LGSideMenuController` for side menu. I'm configure everything for side-menu by storyboard same as available in details of documentation: [LGSideMenuController](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController). I have following configuration for `LGSideMenuController`:

**Configuration Image of LGSideMenuController:**

[image: Configuration Image of LGSideMenuController]

Now, I want to set background colour of side menu as per my `Application` theme, So I have set my side menu controller's background colour from storyboard which is `(0, 105, 255)` respective to `RGB`.

I have ran app, but getting following output.

[image: Side Menu with black background Colour]

So, to take out this issue I have added following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 105.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

But this may have different colour than my actual colour. See following image.

```
self.window?.isOpaque = false
```

[image: Side Menu with blue background Colour]

I have also tried to set window's Opaque property to false as follow, but it's not working:

Please help to solve out this. Help will be appreciated !!!

Comment: Thanks for support. I have tried this, but it's not working.

Comment: oh can u update the question on what have you tried

Comment: @MohmmadS, Updated

Comment: Have you tried `sideMenuController.leftViewBackgroundColor = your custom color` (or `rightViewBackgroundColor`...)?

Comment: @AhmadF, I have tried same in my SideMenuVC but not worked, where to use this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `leftViewBackgroundColor` from storyboard. Add following key path and select type as `UIColor` and set your custom color. See following image:

[image: Menu Background Colour]

Or, You can also directly set from Attribute Inspector as follow:

[image: Attribute Inspector]

I hope this will fix you issue.